# Spreadsheet formula for adding all values adjecent to multiple instances of text cells

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2007

Given a table with unique and duplicate text values in a column with number values adjacent in the following format:

**A|12

B|23

C|98

A|66

D|86

E|3

B|25

A|65

.

.

.**

*The values are simplified for the example. They are actually longer and the ones in column one are letter and number value combinations and punctuation in cases. e.g. "**/ab12345.html**","**/ab23456789/**"*

I need to add the adjacent values of text cells from the first column and end up with a separate 2nd column set of only unique numbers in Column "A" and their values in column "B" to be the SUM of all their adjacent values from the original set.

In essence like so:

**A|143

B|48

C|98

D|86

E|3**

Comment: Question edited. This is a Q and A site, not a forum. Here, we like the question to be concise and to the point. The question you have is OK but it lacks what you've tried. [Please edit your question](http://superuser.com/posts/1071183/edit) and show the formula/VBa you've attempted as it will help us to understand better :)

Answer (score 0):

```
A   12  A   =C1&SUM(IF($A$1:$A$8=C1;$B$1:$B$8))
B   23  B   B48
C   98  C   C98
A   66  D   D86
D   86  E   E3
E   3       
B   25      
A   65
```

The formula is an Array formula and must be entered with ctrl+shift+enter. Column C is a column with all the unique values in column A.

Comment: Can you explain how column `C` get its value? How does this deal with *ones in column one are letter and number value combinations and punctuation in cases* as outlined by the OP?

Comment: If I'm reading the question right (big "if"), I think the D column is supposed to be just the sum associated with the value in C rather than a concatenated value.